# Why Gensim most similar in doc2vec gives the same vector as the output?

Tags: nlp, data-mining, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am using the following code to get the ordered list of user posts.

```
model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load(doc2vec_model_name)
doc_vectors = model.docvecs.doctag_syn0
doc_tags = model.docvecs.offset2doctag

for w, sim in model.docvecs.most_similar(positive=[model.infer_vector('phone_comments')], topn=4000):
        print(w, sim)
        fw.write(w)
        fw.write(" (")
        fw.write(str(sim))
        fw.write(")")
        fw.write("\n")

fw.close()
```

However, I am also getting the vector `"phone comments"` (that I use to find nearest neighbours) in like 6th place of the list. Is there any mistake I do in the code? or is it a issue in Gensim (becuase the vector cannot be a neighbour of itself)?

**EDIT**

Doc2vec model training code

```
######Preprocessing
docs = []
analyzedDocument = namedtuple('AnalyzedDocument', 'words tags')
for key, value in my_d.items():
    value = re.sub("[^1-9a-zA-Z]"," ", value)
    words = value.lower().split()
    tags = key.replace(' ', '_')
    docs.append(analyzedDocument(words, tags.split(' ')))

sentences = []  # Initialize an empty list of sentences
######Get n-grams
#Get list of lists of tokenised words. 1 sentence = 1 list
for item in docs:
    sentences.append(item.words)

#identify bigrams and trigrams (trigram_sentences_project) 
trigram_sentences_project = []
bigram = Phrases(sentences, min_count=5, delimiter=b' ')
trigram = Phrases(bigram[sentences], min_count=5, delimiter=b' ')

for sent in sentences:
    bigrams_ = bigram[sent]
    trigrams_ = trigram[bigram[sent]]
    trigram_sentences_project.append(trigrams_)

paper_count = 0
for item in trigram_sentences_project:
    docs[paper_count] = docs[paper_count]._replace(words=item)
    paper_count = paper_count+1

# Train model
model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec(docs, size = 100, window = 300, min_count = 5, workers = 4, iter = 20)

#Save the trained model for later use to take the similarity values
model_name = user_defined_doc2vec_model_name
model.save(model_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `infer_vector()` method expects a list-of-tokens, just like the `words` property of the text examples (`TaggedDocument` objects, usually) that were used to train the model.

You're supplying a simple string, `'phone_comments'`, which will look to `infer_vector()` like the list `['p', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'e', '_', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't', 's']`. Thus your origin vector for the `most_similar()` is probably garbage.

Further, you're not getting back the input `'phone_comments'`, you're getting back the different string `'phone comments'`. If that's a tag-name in the model, then that must have been a supplied `tag` during model training. Its superficial similarity to `phone_comments` may be meaningless - they're different strings.

(But it may also hints that your training had problems, too, and trained the text that should have been `words=['phone', 'comments']` as `words=['p', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'c', 'o', 'm', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't', 's']` instead.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer :) I have updated my question with my doc2vec training code. As you have mentioned I am using `TaggedDocument` objects. Could you please kindly let me know where I am making the mistake? :)

Comment: By the way `phone_comment` is a tag I used in tarining (that have alist of comments related to phones)

Comment: What is the current problem? Are you getting the same results after fixing what you supply to `infer_vector()` to be a list-of-tokens? (You shouldn't.) After making that fix, what if anything is wrong with the results?

Comment: Can you please kindly suggest me what I should mention in `infer_vector()` as it is not very clear for me? Did you mean something like `model.infer_vector(['phone_comments'])`? :)

Comment: The infer_vector() method expects a list-of-tokens, just like the words property of the text examples that were used to train the model. So if you would have supplied a text during training with `words=['phone', 'comments']`, to infer a vector for a similar text you'd need to do `infer_vector(['phone', 'comments'])`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Sorry, I still do not get it. For `doc_tags = model.docvecs.offset2doctag` `print(doc_tags)`, I get the output as as `'phone_comments', 'car_comments', 'houses_comments', 'tv_comments', ...`. My tags are not separate words like `['phone', 'comments']`. In that case, should not I use `['phone_comments']`? i.e. `model.infer_vector(['phone_comments'])`?

Comment: The `infer_vector()` method is used to create a new doc-vector from a new text. Thus you should supply it the `words` of a new document. You don't provide it any existing tag. If you want to get the vector that was trained during bulk-training for one of the tags you supplied then, you just look it up using indexed-access:  `model.docvecs['phone_comments']`.